# How to create and deploys apps automatically

Tags: heroku, web, deployment

I'm creating a platform that allows users to customize a website template, generate a webapp based on that template, and deploy it on new web address. The webapp creation and deployment process needs to be done automatically through scripts. I'm trying to use Heroku to do this, but it seems that most people create webapps manually. How can I configure heroku to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to add support in your app for the [Heroku Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button).

If that doesn't accomplish what you need, take a look at [Setting Up Apps Using the Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-up-apps-using-the-heroku-platform-api).